# How do I plot a FFT graph from data in a .txt file?

Tags: matlab, fft

Just letting you know I don't have vast knowledge on Matlab and Fast Fourier Transformation so I need some help. I have data in a .txt file of time and voltage (mV) as shown below. I need help plotting this on a FFT graph.

I've Googled different kinds of code online, but can't understand anything as I mainly work with Java - yet that is also very hard to understand and I've heard matlab is easier for this.

Here is a short excerpt from the .txt file:

```
00:04:05,468    0,0996  
00:04:05,469    0,0797  
00:04:05,471    0,0398  
00:04:05,472    -0,0598 
00:04:05,473    -0,1793 
00:04:05,473    -0,1594 
00:04:05,474    -0,2191 
00:04:05,475    -0,1793 
00:04:05,477    -0,1992 
00:04:05,478    -0,1594
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to get the data loaded into MATLAB. There are a variety of ways to load data from a text file. A very simple solution is to [use the Import Tool in the GUI, which will walk you through the process interactively](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-data-interactively.html). Alternatively, you can load the data programmatically using the [`textscan` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

Then, once you have the data loaded, you need to generate an FFT. I've always found this to be confusing, as well, not being either a MATLAB programmer or a signal-processing expert.

A very basic sample code sequence for that follows, with descriptive comments explaining what the purpose of each step is. This code assumes that your sample vector containing the data you loaded from the file is named `samples`; `samples` should contain the voltage values. If you've named this variable something different, then modify the code accordingly.

```matlab
# Define the sampling rate (frequency), which has units of Hz (samples per second)
Fs = # TODO

# Calculate the time interval (the rate of change), which as units of seconds per sample.
dt = 1/Fs;

# Get the number of samples.
N = length(samples);

# Calculate the total time in seconds.
tt = N/Fs;

# Generate a time vector, starting at time 0, incrementing in intervals of dt,
# and ending at time tt (subtract one unit of time, dt, from the ending value
# to match the length of the sample vector).
t = (0 : dt : tt - dt)';

# Get the length of the time vector.
L = size(t, 1);

# Convert the time vector into a frequency vector,
# for the purposes of plotting it.
dF = Fs/L;                       # change in frequency (Hz)
f = (-Fs/2 : dF : Fs/2 - dF);    # frequency vector (like time vector above)

# Calculate the FFT of your sample vector.
x = fftshift(fft(samples));

# Generate a vector of amplitudes (voltages).
y = abs(x)/L;

# Plot it, with the frequency vector as the x-axis
# and the amplitude (voltage) as the y-axis.
plot(f, y);
```

The above code assumes that your samples are evenly distributed (i.e., collected at periodic time intervals) across the sampling interval. From the excerpt of the data file that you've shown, it looks like that is a reasonable assumption. If not, you can modify the code to load the actual time values from the file into a vector, and then use those.